# Problems with enumerate and itemize in beamer

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to create lists for my presentation in beamer. Itemize environments are compiled, but the bullet points are not shown. Enumerate environments cannot be compiled however. Even if I try something as simple as

```
\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Test
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
```

I get the error message: ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255].

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a MWE. Pasting your code fragment in an otherwise default document works without errors.

Comment: Are you using the `enumitem` package? This would explain the error

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, I am using enumitem. I removed it and now it works. Thanks a lot! What's the compatibility issue with enumitem?

Comment: @samcarter Sorry! It turned out that enumitem was the issue.